# How to examine SharedPreferences from adb shell?

Tags: android, adb, android-sharedpreferences

Now that we can [Examining sqlite3 Databases from a Remote Shell](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite), is it possible to examine SharedPreferences from adb shell? Since it would be much more convenient to examine and manipulate SharedPreferences from command line when debugging.

Or put in another way, in what files SharedPreferences are saved, and how to view and modify these files?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Fine, I found the file just after I raised the question above. (It seem asking questions publicly stimulate me to search answers by myself much more diligently, since I don't want my dear peers to view me as a lazy programmer.)

It is an XML file under `/data/data/your.app.package.name/shared_prefs`, and the file name is your.app.package.name_preferences.xml. It is really easy to modify the preferences when you figure out that the content is just a key-value map.

Comment: As asked, how can you edit it?! VI and Nano editors are not installed. How do you edit it than???

Comment: so what about when you have the flag mode_private when you write the preferences... where the file goes?

Comment: Note that under some conditions, the file might end up in a different directory, for instance `/data/user_de/0/your.app.package.name/shared_prefs`. Don't be afraid of searching a bit

Answer (score 47):

If the app is **debugable** you could do:

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as <app-package-id>
$ cat /data/data/<app-package-id>/shared_prefs/prefs.xml
```

Note that the preference might be stored in another file so better
check the directory to find it:

```
$ ls /data/data/<app-package-id>/shared_prefs/
```

Comment: On newer versions the default path is `/data/user/0/<app-package-id>...`

Comment: You need root access for this to work, otherwise you will get a `Permission denied`

Comment: @Oush do you mean the Android device itself must be rooted or is it sufficient to use ** adb root**?

Answer (score 13):

I am using this convenient one-liner to pull, edit in vim, and push shared preferences for an app:

```
APP_ID=com.myapp; adb pull /data/data/${APP_ID}/shared_prefs/${APP_ID}_preferences.xml /tmp/${APP_ID}_preferences.xml && vim /tmp/${APP_ID}_preferences.xml && adb push /tmp/${APP_ID}_preferences.xml /data/data/${APP_ID}/shared_prefs/
```

Just set `APP_ID` to your application id.

Note that this assumes you are using the default file name for shared preferences, as obtained from `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. Also, ADB needs to be running in root mode: `adb root`

Comment: It gives permission denied error on Android emulator.

Answer (score 6):

Helper bash function

```
function adb-pull-prefs {
    # ${1} - app package
    # ${2} - prefs name
    adb exec-out run-as ${1} cat /data/data/${1}/shared_prefs/${2}.xml
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else is running into "Permission Denied" errors using all of the above suggestions like I was, you may need to use `exec-out` like this:

```
adb exec-out run-as <package.name> cat /data/data/<package.name>/shared_prefs/<package.name>_preferences.xml
```

Comment: package debuggable is needed

Comment: only this has worked for me among all the answers listed here.

Answer (score 1):

First pull shared preferences file from device. This requires root permision.

```
adb pull /data/data/org.test/shared_prefs/MyKeys.xml MyKeys.xml
```

Now MyKeys.xml is stored in current directory of your system.

Modify values by

```
vim MyKeys.xml
```

After editing file save changes and push to device.

```
adb push MyKeys.xml /data/data/org.test/shared_prefs/MyKeys.xml
```

To Verify your changes

```
adb shell
cat /data/data/org.test/shared_prefs/MyKeys.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for Flutter, the file is `/data/data/your.app.package.name/shared_prefs/FlutterSharedPreferences.xml`. Note that if you edit the file, you must restart your app for your changes to be visible to your app. Doing a hot reload/hot restart doesn't expose your manual changes to your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to **edit** Shared Preferences **from adb** scripts, please see how to get root on Android emulator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator). (If using 'adb root' is not enought in your case).

If you wish to install vi editor/busybox on Android go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900603/how-to-install-busybox-in-android-using-adb). [OPTIONAL]

To edit a shared preference value, you need to first *COPY app's xml file to SDstorage, copy it to your local filesystem, edit and then upload back* to the phone.

```
adb shell
su
cp /data/data/com.your.package.name/shared_prefs/com.your.package.name_preferences.xml /storage/emulated/0/
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/com.your.package.name_preferences.xml
nano com.your.package.name_preferences.xml
adb push com.your.package.name_preferences.xml /storage/emulated/0/com.your.package.name_preferences.xml
cp /storage/emulated/0/com.your.package.name_preferences.xml /data/data/com.your.package.name/shared_prefs/com.your.package.name_preferences.xml
```

Don't forget to **RESTART the app** to see the results.