# Android refuses to write/create sharedpreferences file

Tags: android, emulation, commit, adb, sharedpreferences

I am using the Eclipse 3.5.2 IDE for Android development.  I am using the following code to write to the default sharedpreferences file and I am running it in the **adb emulator**:

```
private SharedPreferences getOurSharedPreferences(Activity act) {
    // return getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return act.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private void putStringToStorage(Activity act, String keyName, String s) {

    // Store it.
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getOurSharedPreferences(act);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.remove(keyName);
    // editor.putString(keyName, s);
    editor.putString(keyName, "test123");
    boolean bCommitted = editor.commit();
    if (!bCommitted) 
        throw new RuntimeException("(AndroidApplication) Unable to save new string.");

    // Get it back as a test.
    // String s2 = getStringFromStorage(keyName);
}
```

The above method belongs to an **Application** sub-class of mine, that is why the method carries an **Activity** object parameter so I can have access to **Activity.getPreferences()**.  Note, previously I was using the global **getSharedPreferences()** call but I changed to **getPreferences()** out of desperation due to the problems I am having.  The reason I am writing "*test123*" instead of the variable "*s*" is to make sure the problem I'm having is not related to some value of "*s*" that perhaps the shared preferences file might not like.

Whenever I run the code **editor.commit()** always comes back **FALSE**.  Some history.  A while back I was able to write to the shared preferences file using a shared preferences file named "app_global", created by using the global **getSharedPreferences()** call instead of **Activity.getPreferences()**.  I was able to write and read value from that shared preferences file, however, whenever I re-launched my app the values I wrote during the last session were gone.  As part of my debugging efforts I went into the **adb shell** and deleted "app_global" from my app's shared_prefs folder.  Ever since then the emulator appears unwilling to create a new shared preferences file, default one or otherwise.

Note, the **LogCat** window is always empty and the **Console** window does not show any errors, including during the launch of my application in the emulator.  I also tried launching the application in Debug mode with "*Wipe User Data*" checked in the Debug configuration.  That did nothing to help either.  No matter what I do **editor.commit()** fails and the **shared_prefs** folder for my application when doing an "*ls -a*" from the adb shell **is always empty**.

My questions are:

- I read in passing somewhere about "*rebuilding the user image*" for the emulator.  Is that a technique I could use to try to fix this cluster of problems I am having with shared preference storage? If so, how do I do that?
- Is there anything else I could try to fix this problem?

-- roschler

Comment: Just a side note: It is not really good practice to throw a RuntimeException.

Comment: Have you tried using commit() after editor.remove(keyName); ?

Comment: No but I solved the problem.  See my "self-reply" below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem by *manually recreating the sharedpreferences file*.  I can't be certain of this, but it appears that if you manually delete a sharedpreferences file belonging to the emulator, it will not recreate it even if you choose the "*Wipe User Data*" option.  To manually recreate the sharedpreferences file I did the following:

- Load the ADB shell
- Change to the sharedpreferences folder (note you must have the emulator running or you will get a "*device not found*" error, assuming you don't have a phone connected either)
- Create an empty file with the name of the sharedpreferences file you use in your code.  In my case I created a file called "app_global".

You can find the sharedpreferences folder here:

```
/data/data/your.app.package.name/shared_prefs
```

Where *your.app.package.name* is your application's package name.  To create the empty file from within the ADB shell I used the command:

```
echo -n >app_global
```

Where "app_global" is whatever you named your sharedpreferences file.  The **-n** option prevents a line feed from being thrown into the file.  If you are using **getPreferences()** then the name of the default sharedpreferences file is "your.app.package.name_preferences.xml".

I got the information about the sharedpreferences folder from this StackOverflow post:

[How to examine SharedPreferences from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243079/how-to-examine-sharedpreferences-from-adb-shell)

-- roschler