# how to install busybox in android using adb

Tags: android-emulator, adb, busybox

I am trying to install busybox on an android emulator.

I downloaded and compiled busybox and have the busybox binary on my pc.

i then did `adb push busybox /data/local/tmp`

then did `adb shell`, then `#cd /data/local/tmp` , then `#chmod 777 busybox`, then tried `#./busybox --install` it says busybox command not found.

I also copied the file to `/system/busybox`. but `./busybox --install` says `busybox command not found`.

Answer (score 6):

First do `adb push busybox /data/local/busybox`
to copy the busybox into the android phone system
then go to the android shell by doing `adb shell`.
Get the superuser by typing `su`
from you android phone grant superuser request
then back to the shell and type

```
cd /data/local
chmod 755 busybox
./busybox
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system
mkdir /system/xbin
cp /data/local/busybox /system/xbin
cd /system/xbin
busybox --install .
mount -o ro,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system
sync
reboot
```

**Note**: /dev/block/mtdblock4 may not be the /system partition on every device or emulator. It's best to execute the 'mount' command without parameters first in the shell, and look which device or partition is mounted as /system.

Comment: Can you explain this better?

Comment: The answer by @hayder Jaward helped me, but the /system was not mounted at /dev/block/mtdblock4 in my emulator. In the system shell, type 'mount' and press enter, look at the listing until you find /system in the 2nd column. The first column will have the device, in my case it was /dev/block/sda2. Reboot was not necessary.

Comment: @Aaron Hall - I don't understand your edit "in case of cp command not working try using cat"... The 'cp' command is for copying files, any Unix/Linux derived system (including Android) has it. Similarly, 'cat' is the command for just listing the content of text files in the shell window, so how would cat replace cp?

Comment: ALSO: an easier way to remount the /system partition as read-write is just using 'adb remount' command, not in the Android shell, but on your host computer of course.

Comment: @AaronHall - sorry about that, indeed I should have read the edit history first. Don't know why I had an impression this addition came from you, apologies again. Guess I'll edit the post and delete this sentence, as it's just wrong and confusing.

Comment: @gregko there is no `system` in the list after running `mount`

Answer (score 6):

On a rooted phone, install this apk: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/ru.meefik.busybox/

f-droid is a good option as it is open source and officially allows downloading APKs, unlike the play store, which may not be available on test devices.

That app also has a simple install GUI, but the most reliable way to install it is to do simply:

```
adb shell
cp /data/data/ru.meefik.busybox/files/bin/busybox /system/xbin/
busybox ls
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of small changes to gregko and hayder Jawad's answer to get this working on the Pixel 2 emulator.

You have to start the emulator using the `-writable-system` flag as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670592/cannot-change-android-system-directory-to-rw), otherwise you won't be able to remount the `/system` directory with the rw flag.

On the Pixel 2 emulator, `/system` is mounted at `/dev/block/vda` and `/system/xbin` already exists.

Thus, assuming you've pushed the binary to `/data/local/busybox` as per the first half of the answer, the shell commands to install busybox into the Pixel 2 emulator are

```
su
cd /data/local
chmod 755 busybox
./busybox
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/vda /system
cp /data/local/busybox /system/xbin
cd /system/xbin
busybox --install .
mount -o ro,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/vda /system
sync
reboot
```

The busybox download page might be a bit unclear for beginners (like me). For 32-bit x86 processors, you'll want to use the i686 binary file.

Comment: Found it in `/data/local/busybox`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did the following very simple steps:

1. Download busybox apk to my laptop from [here](https://apkpure.com/busybox/stericson.busybox)
2. Install apk using: `adb install <apk file path>`
3. Run busybox shell: `busybox ash`

Once in shell you can use busybox commands.